# Return data from same row as a given query in Pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark

In Pyspark, a Spark/Hadoop input language: I want to find a keyword in a dataset, like "SJC," and return the text from the second column corresponding to the rows where the keyword "SJC" is found.

For example, the following dataset reads:

[Year] [Delay] [Dest] [Flight #]

|1987|   |-5|  |SJC|    |500|

|1987|   |-5|  |SJC|    |250|

|1987|   |07|   |SFO|    |700|

|1987|   |09|   |SJC|    |350|

|1987|   |-5|  |SJC|    |650|

I want to be able to query "SJC" and return the [Delay] values as a list or string.

I've gotten this far, but no luck:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

logFile = "hdfs://<ec2 host address>:9000/<dataset folder (on ec2)>"
sc = SparkContext("local", "simple app")
logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()
numSJC = logData.filter(lambda line: 'SJC' in line).first()

print "Lines with SJC:" + ''.join(numSJC)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost done it by yourself

Imagine you have a pipe-delimited file `/tmp/demo.txt':

```
Year|Delay|Dest|Flight #
1987|-5|SJC|500
1987|-5|SJC|250
1987|07|SFO|700
1987|09|SJC|350
1987|-5|SJC|650
```

In PySpark you should do this:

```
# First, point Spark to the file
log = sc.textFile('file:///tmp/demo.txt')
# Second, replace each line with array of the values, thus string 
# '1987|-5|SJC|500' is replaced with ['1987', '-5', 'SJC', '500']
log = log.map(lambda line: line.split('|'))
# Now filter leaving only the lists with 3rd element equal to 'SJC'
log = log.filter(lambda x: x[2]=='SJC')
# Now leave only the second column, 'Delay'
log = log.map(lambda x: x[1])
# And here's the result
log.collect()
```

Comment: I haven't tried this algorithm yet, but I'll definitely let you know how it goes! Thanks -Andy

Comment: Ahh... it works, thanks! Just wondering though, instead of pipe-delimited data, what if the data is just in different rows in an excel spreadsheet? Would there be any way to do likewise? Thanks!

Comment: Excel files cannot be parsed natively, think the only option would be to use `wholeBinaryFiles` to load them, and then parse with some 3rd party xls-parsing library. If the data in different *rows* it might be a problem, do you mean different columns?

Comment: Woops! Yes, columns not rows.

Comment: Sorry, the function name is just `binaryFiles`

Comment: It would be just the same with Excel. Your goal is to parse xlsx document and convert it to RDD, which would be a collection of xlsx rows, while each row would be python `List`. Then you would use the same approach as here to filter it and get the related columns